# Class name returned by compile, pre, post but not by Directive Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am accessing the class name and printing them in console. This works fine for compile, pre, post but gets error for directive controller. Can someone resolve?

```js
//module declaration 
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//controller declaration
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
$scope.name = "Peter";
});

//app declaration
app.directive('myStudent',function(){
return{
 template: "Hi! Dear!! {{name}}<br/>",
 compile:function(elem, attr){
  console.log("compile");
  return{
   pre:function(scope,elem,attr){
    console.log("pre" + attr.class);
   },
   post: function(scope,elem,attr){
    console.log("post"+ attr.class);
   }     
  }
 },
 controller: [function(scope, elem, attr){
  console.log("controller" + attr.class);
 }]
}
});
```

```html
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 

<my-student class="one"></my-student> 
<my-student class="two"></my-student> 
<my-student class="three"></my-student> 
<my-student class="four"></my-student> 
<my-student class="five"></my-student> 

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script> 
</body>
```

Comment: What is your snippet supposed to show when run? I doesn't look like it's accessing `name` anywhere. I don't see "Peter" anywhere in the output, not the page (which shows `{{name}}`) or the console (which just shows `compile` repeatedly).

Comment: Comment the controller and you will see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is beacuse you will get the injectable services in the controller. like in controller

- You will get $scope rather then just scope
- You will get $attrs in place of attr

As you can see the $scope and $attrs are the services inbuilt with angular.

So make your controller like

```
controller: function($scope, $attrs){
        console.log("controller" + $attrs.class);
    }
```

or

```
controller: ['$scope','$attrs',function($scope, $attrs){
            console.log("controller" + $attrs.class);
        }]
```

Please follow this [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/oxhY2apRetQfv093K5CP?p=preview)

Comment: The change in the argument name doesn't change anything. This is unlike controller outside directive. Care a fiddle if you unsure.

Comment: @Deadpool this is just not the change in the argument name. it's the way service has been written in angular. for better understanding..please follow some tutorial on angular.

Comment: @Deadpool added a plnkr...and controller is controller, they both are same..you can apply a controller to partial or to directive.